# Qt error when setting the application icon

Tags: qt, icons

I am trying to set the application icon with Qt on windows7. I follow every step as the Qt document says. But I got the error message:

```
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/Makenotepad_resource_res.o] Error 1
```

I put the compiler output:

```
>13:15:35: Running steps for project Makenotepad...
13:15:35: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:15:35: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/build-Makenotepad'
windres -i "..\Saved project\Makenotepad\myapp.rc" -o release\myapp_res.o --include-dir=./"../Saved project/Makenotepad" -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN
windres: can't popen `gcc -E -xc -DRC_INVOKED -I./../Saved\ project/Makenotepad -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN "..\Saved project\Makenotepad\myapp.rc"': No error
Makefile.Release:68: recipe for target 'release/myapp_res.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/build-Makenotepad'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/myapp_res.o] Error 1
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
13:15:36: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Makenotepad (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
13:15:36: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

I have been searching for this issue for half days already, actually, there are many people has the same issues, and there is no clear answers for it. Can someone please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt 5 uses RC_ICONS to set the icon. And it is done from the Project's pro file.

```
RC_ICONS = myappico.ico
```

Did you try the same? Run qmake and try rebuilding the project.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but I got the same error. I have tried to create the .rc file as well, but still not work.

Comment: Clean, Run Qmake, they are all okay. When I build, it always stuck here.

Comment: Are you sure it's happening when you add the icon file?

Comment: Yes, when I remove the line: RC_FILE += myapp.rc;   I can build and run my program correctly.

Comment: Use the other method. RC_ICONS = icon.ico
It is Qt5 right?

Comment: I try to create a new project, and copy the same .ico file and .rc file into the new project, it works well. I guess the project file of the previous program is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with my system environment a while ago so in the project settings I went to Projects > Build (for the selected toolkit) > Build Environment and selected "Clear system environment". This fixed my original build issue but unfortunately due to an apparent bug in how winres works (it's a [terrible program](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62918))  it somehow breaks the command line generation it does.

The fix if you're using a clean system env for building is to add the COMSPEC env variable:

```
COMSPEC  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```

That seems to be enough to fix winres. I'm going to submit a QtCreator bug to get them to add this env by default when selecting a clear sys env.

EDIT: QTCREATOR issue here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23649